# Как генерировать запрос на создание Jira таска?

Tags: python, api, jira

Можно как-то генерировать запрос на создание таска в Jira?

При этом, чтобы я отправлял запрос, и был уже как бы шаблон из темы и сообщения.
И авторизация была под тем пользователем, который нажал на ссылку, а не под тех. пользователем.

Такое реально?
Если да, дайте ссылку, где хоть почитать про такое?

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [JIRA](https://pypi.org/project/jira/), который предоставляет Python обёртку над JIRA API.

[Пример из документации](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#issues):

```
new_issue = jira.create_issue(project='PROJ_key_or_id', summary='New issue from jira-python',
                              description='Look into this one', issuetype={'name': 'Bug'})
```

или используя словарь:

```
issue_dict = {
    'project': {'id': 123},
    'summary': 'New issue from jira-python',
    'description': 'Look into this one',
    'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
}
new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
```

PS знакомство с этим модулем лучше начать [отсюда](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашел генерацию url для создания таска, описание здесь:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-create-issues-using-direct-html-links-in-jira-server-159474.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.